# Error message when trying to 'latex makebst'

Tags: bibliographies, errors, custom-bib

In trying to create a customized bibliography style, I have attempted to run the command `latex makebst` (and alternatively `tex makebst`) but to no avail.  Instead, I get the following error message:

```
! I can't write on file 'makebst.log'.  
Plase type another transcript file name:  
! Emergency stop  
No pages of output.
```

I am using Version 3.1415926 (MiKTeX 2.8), for what it's worth.  Any suggestions/insight on how to correct for this error?

Comment: How exactly are you invoking `latex makebst`?

Comment: You might be trying to do this in the directory where MikTeX is installed & not allowed to write to it. a simple solution might be to copy `makebst.tex` into some temporary directory - making sure that you have write permission to it (check the `Properties` tab for the folder) & run `latex makebst` again.

Comment: Thank you, it indeed was as simple as correcting my permissions for the folders in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your disc is full or you don't have permissions to write in the directory or there is already a file `makebst.log` that you don't have permission to write to.

Is the error message so hard to understand?

Comment: I think the poster was asking how to fix the errors (e.g. change the permissions on which directory).

Comment: @crippledlamda: This is not a general help forum for Windows users.

Comment: The only requirement for using this forum is being an _enthusiastic user of TeX, LaTeX, and related systems_ --a requirement I meet.  The simplicity of my question/problem should not detract from the quality and professionalism of the response(s) it elicits.  For someone who advocates raising _the public awareness of TeX_, I figured you of all people would appreciate the importance of fostering others' understanding of relevant issues.

Comment: The issues of which directories need to be write-enabled for the makebst log file is a relevant issue for tex users I believe.

Comment: @erikp: Touché. I think you can close this question.